Symfony picking up wrong data based on condition in production
System data:
OS Ubuntu's  Timezone: Asia/Tokyo(JST)
MySQL(RDS)'s Timezone: System

cron command
30 * * * * cd project && php bin/console command-name

Running the query builder from EM at the top of execute() of command:
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$newsletters = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Newsletter')->getNewsletterForDelivery()->getQuery()->getResult();

The query builder from the command:
public function getNewsletterForDelivery()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('n')
        ->from('AppBundle:Newsletter', 'n')
        ->andWhere("DATE_FORMAT(n.sendDatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')")
        ->andWhere('n.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('n.sendStatus = :sendStatus')
        ->setParameter('status', Newsletter::STATUS_DEFAULT)
        ->setParameter('sendStatus', Newsletter::SEND_STATUS_WAITING);

    return $qb;
}

My expectations on this query builder is that it will fetch the newsletter for delivering based on the conditions above. However when cron is running the command that runs this query builder, it is not sending on the assigned time but rather after 9 hours.
The condition that has issue is the:
->andWhere("DATE_FORMAT(n.sendDatetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')")

Result:
TITLE     Send Date Time     Actual receive date time
Test 1  | 2024-11-06 16:56 | 2024-11-07 01:30
Test 2  | 2024-11-07 13:00 | 2024-11-07 22:30
test 3  | 2024-11-07 13:25 | 2024-11-07 22:30
Test 4  | 2024-11-13 09:15 | 2024-11-13 18:30 


As you can see, the actual received datetime is about 9 hours after send date time even both mysql and os timezone is set to JST. And so we tried to compensated and adjusted the now to add 9 hours
Below is the code adjustment to include a +9hours time:
public function getNewsletterForDelivery()
{
    // Adjust the `now` +9hours because newsletters are sent after 9hours because of system/symfony timezone issue
    $adjustedNow = new \DateTime(); // Current time
    $adjustedNow->modify('+9 hours'); // Add 9 hours

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('n')
        ->from('AppBundle:Newsletter', 'n')
        // Compare sendDatetime with the adjusted current time
        ->andWhere("DATE_FORMAT(n.sendDatetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT(:adjustedNow, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')")
        ->andWhere('n.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('n.sendStatus = :sendStatus')
        ->setParameter('adjustedNow', $adjustedNow) // Set the adjusted current time
        ->setParameter('status', Newsletter::STATUS_DEFAULT)
        ->setParameter('sendStatus', Newsletter::SEND_STATUS_WAITING);

    return $qb;
}

Result:
TITLE     Send Date Time     Actual receive date time
Test 1  | 2024-11-21 17:00 | 2024-11-21 17:30  OK
Test 2  | 2024-11-21 17:15 | 2024-11-21 17:30  OK
Test 3  | 2024-11-21 17:30 | 2024-11-21 17:30  OK
Test 4  | 2024-11-21 17:45 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK
Test 5  | 2024-11-21 18:00 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK
Test 6  | 2024-11-21 18:15 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK
Test 7  | 2024-11-21 18:30 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK
Test 8  | 2024-11-21 18:45 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK
Test 9  | 2024-11-21 19:00 | 2024-11-21 17:30  NOT OK

And now it is sending the newsletter even if the letters are supposedly not yet to be delivered.
Note1:
Removing the DATE_FORMAT in the condition to compare the raw datetime has the same effect.
Note2:
Manually executing the command from the CLI and trying to fetch one newsletter data
NOW   : 2024-11-22 17:08:18 (current datetime when this was executed)
Test 1: 2024-11-21 17:00:00 (actual datetime from DB)

 meaning running the command manually fetches the correct newsletter
TLDR:
Running manually fetches the correct newsletter (not more than senddate) while cron fetches the newsletter even if senddate is 2 hours after now

What's the difference between the job running manually and running it through Cron?

Updated the question at the bottom

So, what is the actual difference? Did you check whether both instances of PHP (the one you run manually, and the one ran through cron) is using the exact same settings?

The difference is that while manually running the command, I can fetch the correct newsletter while cron fetches the newsletters not yet meant to be sent

Please don't repeat what is happening, but what the difference in the configuration might be. Did you check whether the generated queries are different? If the query builder generates the exact same query in both cases, I would assume that it isn't even involved. And if this is the case, check whether executing the exact same query through PHP itself (not through Doctrine) yields different results

Try adding this inside the execute of command and inside query builder to force PHP/Symfony to use Asia/Tokyo timezone.
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");


Thank you this worked !. not sure why symfony is using UTC when sending the newsletter
